# working with 2 lists

Tags: python

I have two lists: one only contains numbers, while the other contains strings. For example:

```
listA = [ 3, 4, 5, 7]

listB = ["Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His4Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His5Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His7Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]" ]
```

I want to match the number in listA and the bolded words in listB. Ultimately, I want to print the whole string of listB, when I use the number of listA. For example, if I use number 3 in listA I also want to print out this: `Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]`

Comment: I'm missing something- why not `print listA[0], listB[0]`? Also, the edit took away the bold words. Also, it sounds like you should be using a dictionary.

Comment: @MatthewAdams so i basically have to use number from listA to calculate in the program, if the number from listA work then i suppose to print the text that relate to that number.. i have a lot of duplicate on my results as of right now which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in a dictionary? Use `zip`:

```
listAtoB = dict(zip(listA, listB))

listAtoB[3] # Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
```

Comment: how would i use this? so i use the number from listA to calculate, if the number in listA works then i should print text that relate to the number from listA

Comment: @ChadD: Assuming your number from `listA` is `x`, it's just `print(listAtoB[x])`.

Comment: I got this error when i use dict(zip(listA, listB)) --> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @ChadD: Did you call one of your variables `dict`? Don't do that :)

Comment: oh thanks thats where i had the error, but what if there is two 3's on listA even though there is equal number of indexes in both list. can i still use dict(zip(listA, listB))

Comment: @ChadD: Yes, but the duplicates will be eliminated - what do you want to do with them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15969/discussion-between-chad-d-and-minitech)

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
listA = [ 3, 4, 5, 7]
ListB = ["Z2 O95409 V595 p.His3Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 p.His4Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 p.His5Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]", "Z2 O95409 V595 p.His7Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]"]
for x in listA:
    for y in ListB:
        if y[y.index("p.His")+5]==str(x): #if x in "p.HisxLeu"
            print x,y
```

or use `filter()`:

```
for x in listA:
    for y in filter(lambda z:z[z.index("p.His")+5]==str(x),ListB):
        print x,y
```

**output:**

```
3 Z2 O95409 V595 p.His3Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
4 Z2 O95409 V595 p.His4Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
5 Z2 O95409 V595 p.His5Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
7 Z2 O95409 V595 p.His7Leu Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
```

Comment: @ChadD here `index()`will return the index of `p` here, so to get the value of the character after `s` I've added 5 to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to create a dictionary that maps items from listA to items from ListB. If you are on Python >= 2.7 you can use a dictionary comprehension (if not, see other answers that use `dict` to achieve the same):

```
listA = [ 3, 4, 5, 7]
ListB = ['Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]', 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His4Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]', 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His5Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]', 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His7Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]' ]

d = { a:b for a, b in zip(listA, ListB) }
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
{3: 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
 4: 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His4Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
 5: 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His5Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
 7: 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His7Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]'}
```

However, given your requirements, I propose a dictionary of dictionaries to provide lookup to the protein name as well as it's full description.

```
d = { a: {'protein': b.split('**')[1], 'description': b} for a, b in zip(listA, ListB) }
pprint(d)
{3: {'description': 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
     'protein': 'p.His3Leu'},
 4: {'description': 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His4Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
     'protein': 'p.His4Leu'},
 5: {'description': 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His5Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
     'protein': 'p.His5Leu'},
 7: {'description': 'Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His7Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]',
     'protein': 'p.His7Leu'}}
```

Now you can perform lookups like this:

```
>>> print d[3]['protein']
p.His3Leu
>>> print d[3]['description']
Z2 O95409 V595 **p.His3Leu** Dase - Hophaly type 5 (HPE5) [609637]
```

Comment: I like the nested dicts, but I don't think "**" actually exists as a substring in the line.  I'm pretty sure those were introduced by the OP to bold those words, and when the edit was made to mark up the code block, the asterisks became visible.

Comment: @DSM: thanks, yes, I suspect that the "**" is just markup too, but that's what it says in the question. Easy enough to change the `split()` to something appropriate for the data, assume fixed width fields, or use a regex match instead.